# find a target element of a closest specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a `target` image by clicking on the `NEXT` button.
Here is my try but it doesn't work.

```
<div class='gwrap'>
<div class='gins'>
<img class='gimg' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='gimg' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='gimg' src='...' alt='img'> // target
</div>
 <div class='gbtns'>
<div class='gnext'>NEXT</div>
</div>
</div>

$(document).on('click', '.gnext', function(){  
    let a = $(this).closest('.gwrap').find('.gimg:last-child');
    a.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. Just use `parent()` with `closest` like below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.gnext', function() {
  let a = $(this).parent().closest('.gwrap').find('.gimg:last-child');
  a.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='gwrap'>
  <div class='gins'>
    <img class='gimg' src='...' alt='img'>
    <img class='gimg' src='...' alt='img'>
    <img class='gimg' src='...' alt='img'> // target
  </div>
  <div class='gbtns'>
    <div class='gnext'>NEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```